# SVG HTML5 change pattern attributes in specific instance/usage only

Tags: javascript, html, svg, snap.svg

I have a SVG Pattern which I use as fill in many other SVGs.
Of course, when I change attributes in the pattern afterwards, it is changed in every SVG using this pattern.

Is there a possibility to modify the pattern attributes in a specific instance/use only?

I would like to avoid creating the pattern in 100 different versions before.

## EDIT with sample:

This is a sample pattern. I use this icon as fill for a circle on a country on a world map. The circle inside the pattern is used to set the background color.

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
        <defs>
            <pattern id="infantry_svg" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="100% " height="100%">
                <circle r="10" fill="transparent"></circle>
                <path d="M 19.328,3.097 19.025,2.633 18.35,3.045 17.638,2.148 17.555,3.563 15.188,5.011 C 14.818,4.596 14.555,4.484 14.555,4.484 L 10.343,7.079 10.039,6.959 9.871,6.7 13.072,4.919 C 12.811,4.496 12.29,3.65 12.29,3.65 L 9.295,5.893 9.173,5.968 9.028,5.732 8.342,6.155 8.488,6.393 8.276,6.523 7.838,5.811 7.152,6.234 7.59,6.946 7.293,7.129 7.146,6.891 6.46,7.314 6.606,7.551 6.584,7.566 3.881,8.993 4.556,10.089 7.139,8.339 C 7.26,8.536 7.353,8.687 7.353,8.687 l -1.748,1.074 0.293,0.456 -0.373,1.185 -1.518,1.412 c 0,0 -2.772,1.469 -4.007,2.152 0.308,0.691 0.964,1.57 1.443,2.214 0,0 4.855,-4.879 6.706,-4.765 l 1.837,-1.136 c 0,0 -0.752,-0.704 -0.5,-0.864 1.583,1.752 3.062,1.704 3.062,1.704 0.442,-0.568 0.528,-1.221 0.78,-1.834 -1.195,-0.286 -1.226,-0.103 -2.25,-1.111 l 4.673,-2.88 C 15.821,6.048 15.48,5.467 15.48,5.467 l 3.848,-2.37 z m -9.83,8.165 -1.203,0.742 c 0,0 -0.281,-0.437 -0.435,-0.688 l 0.265,-0.16 c 0.168,0.165 0.502,0.417 0.834,0.213 l -0.124,-0.2 C 8.662,11.275 8.461,11.146 8.333,11.03 l 0.743,-0.453 0.422,0.685 z"
                      fill="#030104" transform="translate(1,1.1) scale(0.29)" stroke="white" stroke-width="0.4" />
            </pattern>
        </defs>
    </svg>
```

Now when I set this pattern inside a circle on a country, it looks like this:
[image]

The circle on the country is generated like this with Snap.svg:

```
var circle = xs.circle(x, y, 4).attr({ id: "blabla", fill: "url(#infantry_svg)", stroke: "black", strokeWidth: 1 }).appendTo(xs.select('g'));
```

Directly after this, I set the background color of the pattern used for this circle:

```
$("#infantry_svg circle").attr({fill: troopOwner_color]});
```

Now every circle using "infantry_svg" pattern, has "troopOwner_color" as background color of the circle.

But I would like to change **only this single instance** of the pattern usage.

Comment: That's not possible. You'll need 100 patterns.

Comment: Okay thx, is there maybe a complete other way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I don't know. What do you want to do?

Comment: I want a fill pattern which I can later modify without changing the original pattern, because I want to use the original one as template for other fills.
i.e. I have a icon with a black border as pattern, in one SVG I want to set this icon as fill, but with a white border. In another SVG I want to use this fill pattern with a red border, etc.
Or are there maybe alternatives to that?

Comment: I suspect you can reuse some of the programming code with a library (its not clear what you already have), but end up with similar elements within the DOM itself. So it depends what you are trying to really achieve. If you put an example bit of code showing 2 or so of the patterns, it would help.

Comment: There is a property in the standard to change at least the colors for a pattern. But afaik no browser supports it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst you can't do what you want with the specific requirement of the question, ie using a pattern. I'm not sure why you need to use a pattern.

Why not just use a 'use' element for the defs statement, and have a path & circle in there. Then you can just clone it and change the fill...

```
<defs>
        <g id="infantry_svg" >
            <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="40"  stroke="red" stroke-width="5"/>
            <path>path stuff</path>
 </defs>


var g = s.g().use( Snap.select('#infantry_svg') );

var g1 = s.g( g ).attr({  fill: 'yellow' });
var g2 = g.clone().attr({ fill: 'blue',  transform: 't200,0' })
var g2 = g.clone().attr({ fill: 'green', transform: 't100,0' })
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qd6g5Lhe/7/)

Just include the bits that don't change in the defs element, and create the bits that will be unique.

Comment: Thank you Ian! This is exactly what I need. I didn't know about the use element before.